# Are there any polls on what the citizens of Israel would like to be done to Gaza in response to the recent attack?

Tags: israel, public-opinion, gaza, hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war

Specifically I'm curious how many people support:

- Minimal efforts to secure the border / build a taller fence
- Bombing Hamas headquarters but not much else
- Land-based invasion to eliminate Hamas
- Taking over Gaza and resuming full control
- Expelling Gaza residents to Egypt

I presume that there must be *some* polls by now as this is a huge event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated**: A survey conducted by Prof. Camille Fuchs says:

- 44% believe that Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu is responsible for the failure of October 7, 33% blame the Chief of Staff and senior IDF officers while only 5% blame Defense Minister Yoav Galant.
- 56% said they do not trust Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu's ability to manage the war, 26% said they trust him while 16% said they do not know.
- 55% said Gaza residents should not be allowed to return if Hamas is not defeated, 24% said they should be allowed to return while 21% said they do not know.
- 76% said that Netanyahu has to resign office. But 47% said that Netanyahu should resign after the war is over, while 29% believe he should resign immediately. 18% said Netanyahu needn't resign. 6% said they do not know.
- 68% said that PM Netanyahu and Finance Minister Bezalel Smotrich haven't handled the economy well, while 19% said they have done a good job. 13% said they do not now.
- 74% said a State Commission of Inquiry should investigate the failures that allowed the terrorist attack while 12% said that a Government commission is enoouh. 10% answered they do not know.
- 64% believe that an election should be held after the war while 26% believe that the current government should continue in office. 10% of respondents answered they do not.

*(The survey included 691 respondents, of which 591 were from the Jewish population and 100 from the non-Jewish sector. The questioning in the Jewish sector was conducted by the company headed by Dr. Ariel Ayalon. The questioning in the non-Jewish sector was conducted by the State Net company headed by Yosef Makleda. The sampling error is 3.7%)*.

---

**A survey conducted on October 18 and 19**, commissioned by the *Maariv* newspaper and conducted by the [Lazar Institute](https://www.lazar-institute.org/) and [Panel4All](https://www.panel4all.co.il/) says:

- 65% of Israelis support a ground offensive in Gaza, while 21% oppose it.
- 51% backed a large-scale military operation on the northern front, at Israel’s border with Lebanon, with Hamas and Hezbollah terrorists, while 30% want a limited operation.
- 80% of Israelis said Netanyahu must publicly accept responsibility for the staggering failures which lead to the terrorist attack, while 8% of the general public think he should not.
- 49% believe that National Unity party leader Benny Gantz is better suited to be the Prime Mnister and only 28% picked Netanyahu, with the rest undecided.
- Asked who they would vote for if elections are held today, Gantz's National Unity party was projected to win 40 seats, from its current 12. The current ruling coalition would lose 21 seats and from their present strength of 64 seats.

*(The survey queried 510 respondents and the margin of error was 4.3%).*

**Reference**:

1. [Poll: 80% of Israelis say Netanyahu must take public responsibility for Oct. 7 failures](https://www.timesofisrael.com/poll-80-of-israelis-say-netanyahu-must-take-public-responsibility-for-oct-7-failures/).
2. [News poll 13: Who is responsible for the failure - and should Netanyahu resign?](https://13tv.co.il/item/news/politics/politics/new-poll-903784948/) *(Translated)*.

Comment: Great, thank you! Any surveys for the "push them out to Egypt" option, by any chance?

Comment: @JonathanReez See updates - new survey says 55% believe Gaza residents shouldn't be allowed back if Hamas is not defeated.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like the [Elon Peace Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Peace_Plan) has a non-trivial chance of being carried out this decade.

Comment: @JonathanReez That plan sounds like joke - the king of Jordan once fought of a [rebellion of Palestinian refugees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_September) who tried to overthrow him and capture power. One has to be delusional to believe such a state would willingly allow millions of Palestinians to settle in their country again.